# Unable to receive firebase notification

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send fcm notification via a simple curl request and confirm whether they are getting it on browser or not.

My code

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "gcm_sender_id": "103953800507"
}
```

**app.js**

```
 var config = {
        apiKey: "<API KEY>",
        authDomain: "<ddd>",
        databaseURL: "<dd>",
        projectId: "<dd>",
        storageBucket: "<bb>",
        messagingSenderId: "<Server Id>"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  const messaging = firebase.messaging();
  messaging.requestPermission().then(function() {
     //getToken(messaging);
     return messaging.getToken();
  }).then(function(token){
  console.log(token);
  })
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log('Permission denied', err);
});


messaging.onMessage(function(payload){
  console.log('onMessage: ',payload);
});
```

**firebase-messaging-sw.js**

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js');


  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
        apiKey: "<API KEY>",
        authDomain: "<dd>",
        databaseURL: "<dd>",
        projectId: "<dd>",
        storageBucket: "<dd>",
        messagingSenderId: "<SERVER KEY>"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

</head>
<body>
    My firebase app 
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I am running the index.html for first time, it is showing the popup for subscribing to notifications and returns the token

Now then I send the message using curl command

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key=<SERVER API KEY>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -d '{
  "data": {
    "notification": {
        "title": "FCM Message",
        "body": "This is an FCM Message"
    }
  },
  "to": "<DEVICE KEY>"
}' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

and the response is

```
{"multicast_id":7157312120735409,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1531738949596250%7031b6f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

but still I am not getting messaging.onMessage triggered? What am i missing?

Is there a way I can see list of messages send and there status on firebase console?

Comment: idk if "data" is supposed to be the top object in your request, as I have only done this via a client like postman, my objects are like 
      ```{
      "data":{...},
      "notification":{...},
      ...}```
Read up on 'Data' vs 'Notification' FCM payloads, if it's ```Data``` you're using you have to check the command in the received FCM payload in your designated FCMMessagingService. If it's ```Notification``` the OS will show it if you have defined the required UI elements.
Also try topic subscription first and ensure you've got the right app assigned to the id you're using to send.

Comment: "**Is there a way I can see list of messages send and their status on firebase console?**" You can send these from the FCM Console, these are received as 'Notification' notifications. These are like the easy way to FCM. It has built in analytics. Without this, you should really log your own FCM requests and store ids and outcomes in some db. You can send "Data" and "Notification" payloads via curl commands (etc) but only "Notification" payloads via the console

Comment: I am not seeing any option to send notifications from firebase console to web app.It is displaying only 2 options (android, ios)

Comment: Hey Ankit, if you want to FCM, you can use http client like curl to send request, or FCM console. For FCM Console go to **Grow>CloudMessaging**. These notifications will be magically picked up and displayed by android as long as you set it up right. These are called "Notification" notifications (confusing name yes.). Otherwise you send "Data" notifications. These are ***not*** magically shown up as UI Notifications - you have to write code to display a notification in your FirebaseMessagingService for "Data" notifications. 

Just check your request and re-read the tutorial you're doing

Comment: My bad, I misread. Your request is different from the one they give you, try that and lemme know:

```{ "notification": {
    "title": "Background Message Title",
    "body": "Background message body",
    "click_action" : "https://dummypage.com"
  },

  "to" : "<DEVICE_KEY_OR_TOPIC>"

}``` from the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive

Comment: Worked.. Thanks man..

Comment: Happy days! My bantering about "Data" and "Notification" types is still worth keeping in mind, these always cause confusion. Bon chance ;)